# Node: Cannot find module "mongoose" / Cannot install mongoose correctly

Tags: mongoose

wenn i try to start a javascript-file with a test connection to mongodb then I get the Error message that the mongoose module cannot find. I have installed the mongoose with "npm install mongoose" in my node.js directory. But when I install mongoose then I get following messages, so I thin its not installed correctly:

```
> kerberos@0.0.10 install C:\Zimmermann\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_module
s\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

C:\Zimmermann\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mon
godb-core\node_modules\kerberos>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Zim
mermann\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bi
n\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)

> bson@0.2.21 install C:\Zimmermann\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mo
ngodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Zimmermann\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mon
godb-core\node_modules\bson>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Zimmerm
ann\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\no
de-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)
mongoose@4.0.1 node_modules\mongoose
├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
├── sliced@0.0.5
├── hooks-fixed@1.0.1
├── mpromise@0.5.4
├── muri@1.0.0
├── mpath@0.1.1
├── async@0.9.0
├── kareem@1.0.0
├── ms@0.1.0
├── mquery@1.4.0 (debug@0.7.4, bluebird@2.3.2)
└── mongodb@2.0.24 (readable-stream@1.0.31, mongodb-core@1.1.20)
```

What can I do that mongoose works correctly? Does anyone have an idea?

Best regards Benny

Answer (score 2):

You can do  either of two things to make it run :-

1) **Install mongoose globally** with below steps :-

a)`npm install mongoose -g`

b) Go to your app directory, where module.js is located and then run

`npm link mongoose`

Explanation :- When you install a package globally via npm, it is downloaded to global node_module folder. For me(Mac user), it's under */usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose*. We link this to that directory from where you are trying to run node.js.

2) **Another approach is to install mongoose locally, not globally** via

`npm install mongoose`

After following either of these, you will be seeing node_modules --> mongoose folder under the 'node.js' directory, which means mongoose has been successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

This block

```
mongoose@4.0.1 node_modules\mongoose
    ├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
    ├── sliced@0.0.5
    ├── hooks-fixed@1.0.1
    ├── mpromise@0.5.4
    ├── muri@1.0.0
    ├── mpath@0.1.1
    ├── async@0.9.0
    ├── kareem@1.0.0
    ├── ms@0.1.0
    ├── mquery@1.4.0 (debug@0.7.4, bluebird@2.3.2)
    └── mongodb@2.0.24 (readable-stream@1.0.31, mongodb-core@1.1.20)
```

shows that mongoose has been installed correctly

You can use it like this

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' )
```

If the install had failed, you would see a block that looks more like this:

```
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/josh/.npm/mongoose/4.0.1/package.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.3-3-ARCH
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "mongoose"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.8.3
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/josh/npm-debug.log
```

### Takeaway

Output text does **not** mean the command failed. Look for actual error messages.

Comment: Hi, i was not sure about this. But why I get the messsage that the module "Mongoose" cannot be found. I tried it with var bla = require(' mongoose') but the message shows me that something is wrong :(. MongoDB is running. What can be the reason? Perhaps in wrong directory?

Comment: That sounds like you are in the wrong directory. The file you are running must have a `node_modules` directory in  the same directory or one of the parents